# Asterisk who is calling every minute?

Tags: asterisk, voip, pbx

I know the basics of [Asterisk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA00D.jpg) . When I go into the console by running the command `asterisk -rvvv` I see the following:

[image]

If you notice I first get a notice:

> [Aug 24 19:14:43] NOTICE[5097][C-00000036]: chan_sip.c:25877
>   handle_request_invite: Call from '' (62.210.26.82:5079) to extension
>   '011972599166454' rejected because extension not found in context
>   'default'.

and then I get a warning and this happens every minute.

**So my question is who is dailing extension 011972599166454 ?** If I add:

```
[default]   
exten => _X.66454,1,NoOp(Hanging up call)
same  => n, Hangup
```

to my extensions.conf file this solves the problem. But why is someone making a call every minute? to open the NAT? Should I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just ban the IP address with your firewall and forget it.

If you are curious, you can set `sip set debug ip <ip>` and check SIP headers, maybe you could find some info about callee in the headers.
Also you can trace the IP with `whois` and try to find admins' contact to discuss the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is scanning bot looking for free calls.
Just disable guest calling `sip.conf: allowguest=no`. Then any not authenticated connections will be ignored. It will help with new IPs also.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+allowguest

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is an attempt of hacking...
Use [Fail2Ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban%20:Fail2Ban) for blocking any suspected attempts to call.